# configure multiple https websites in azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-virtual-machine

I have two websites and two different ssl certificates.
I have an Azure windows VM.
I have configured website1 to port 443, applied one certificate, added inboud rule of https(port 443) rule from azure portal.
I have one more website which i want to be accessible over https.
I have another ssl certificate.
I hosted this website on port 444, added certificate.
the problem is azure portal only allows port:443 inbound rule.

[image]

How can i host multiple https websites on windows azure vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How can i host multiple https websites on windows azure vm?**

1.You need open port 444 on Windows Firewall(Inbound rule). More information about open ports on Windows Firewall please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345310(v=sql.100).aspx).

2.You need open port 444 on Azure NSG rule(Inbound rule).

[image]

Comment: I followed this to open port 444 in inbound rule. http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall/ but no luck

Comment: Could you access your website by using `https://127.0.0.1:444` on your VM? You should ensure the port 444 is listening. You could use `netstat -ant` to check.

Comment: It seems a firewall issue. Azure NSG could associate on `NIC` and `subnet`. Do you check all? Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal#associate-the-nsg-to-the-frontend-subnet).

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt For now, you could access port 443 but could not port 444?

Comment: When i access by `https://localhost:444/` I get `Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from abc.com (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` in google chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135749/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-markand-bhatt).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should create a custom rule for port 444, Azure doesn't really inspect traffic, so those labels (https,ssh,rdp, etc) are only for your convenience.

Also (apart from nsg rule), you should enable port 444 on windows firewall, make sure you app listens on 444 and make sure you can connect to a vm

Comment: I tried this too. But it doenst seem to be working. Anything else do i have to do apart from just adding an inbound rule?